# Generar un numero de folio diferente cada vez que se guarda un registro

Tags: php, html

```html
<div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="inputBox">
                  <div class="inputText">*Fecha Activacion</div>
                  <input type="date" name="fecha" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="date" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="inputBox">
                  <div class="inputText">*Fecha de corte</div>
                  <input type="date" name="fecha_cor" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="date" readonly required>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="submit" name="" id="" class="button" value="Guardar registro" onClick="comprobarClave()">
              </div>
            </div>
```

Mi problema es querer generar un numero de folio cada vez que se inserte un registro a la base de datos, que sea diferente, si tienen algun pedazo de codigo que haga eso y me lo puedan proporcionar se los agradeceria o un link donde pueda guiarme.

Comment: No veo que sea necesario que lo genere php. Pudieras usar el id del folio que genera la base de datos. Cada vez que se genere uno nuevo el id incrementa entonces siempre seria distinto.

Comment: Que tal @Archagy, bueno puede ser pero quiero mostrar el folio al momento de guardarlo, tipo de este es tu numero de folio, nombre del cliente, etc.

Comment: Mismo escenario. El usuario guarda la informacion y se genera un id nuevo en la tabla folios. Puedes mostrar un modal y que muestre el ultimo registro agregado, podrias igual que la consulta haga referencia al id del usuario para que siempre muestre el ultimo id correcto de folio por usuario.

Comment: El modal lo pondria en el archivo donde mando a insertar los datos de la base de datos, al principio de toda la consulta?

Comment: encuentro que la idea del **auto incremental** es la más optima, pero mi pregunta es la siguiente:
si quieres generar un **numero de folio** quieres que se genere por un numero random o por especificaciones?

Comment: random, cada venta que se haga genere un folio diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar un folio a partir de las fechas establecidas de tu formulario y que ese se mande a tu php

```
function comprobarClave(){
   var fecha= $('#fecha').val();
   var fecha_cor= $('#fecha_cor').val();
   var fechaIniFormat = fecha.split("-"), fechaFinFormat = fecha_cor.split("-");
   return fechaIniFormat+fechaFinFormat+Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
}
```